# how to convert sealed class in kotlin to java

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to kotlin, how can I convert this kotlin code to java

```
sealed class TokenCommandResult {
    class Success(val response: OIDCTokenResponse) : TokenCommandResult()
    class Error(val error: TokenErrorResponse) : TokenCommandResult()
    class Fault(val exception: Throwable) : TokenCommandResult()
}


when (result) {
            is TokenCommandResult.Success -> printToken(format, result.response.oidcTokens.accessToken.value)
}
```

This is what I came up with, but I need repeat this code three times, is there a easier way to do that?

```
public static final class Success extends TokenCommandResult {      
      private final OIDCTokenResponse response;

      
      public final OIDCTokenResponse getResponse() {
         return this.response;
      }

      public Success( OIDCTokenResponse response) {
         
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Java 16 or above, you can use [sealed interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/language/sealed-classes-and-interfaces.html) and [records](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/language/records.html) in Java to do roughly the same thing.

```java
public sealed TokenCommandResult permits Success, Error, Fault {
    record Success(OIDCTokenResponse response) implements TokenCommandResult {}
    record Error(TokenErrorResponse error) implements TokenCommandResult {}
    record Fault(Throwable exception) implements TokenCommandResult {}
}
```

The amount of code this has is more comparable to the Kotlin version, but do note that a record class is more similar to a Kotlin `data class` rather than a regular Kotlin class.

If you are using something before Java 16, you can use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org) to reduce the boilerplate:

```java
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public static final class Success extends TokenCommandResult {      
    private final OIDCTokenResponse response;
}
```